# Extract numbers from a string?! Java

Tags: string, get, numbers, extract

For my program I am trying to figure how I can go about taking a series of number as string entered by the user; extract each number at spaces and parse them into integers.

P.S I am still a newbie to the programming languages so please explain in a way that I can understand, thanks.

This is what I have so far:

A user may input a series of number like this: 15 31 94 87 108 11 7 63 79

```
public int [] getNumbers (){

    Scanner reader = new Scanner (System.in);

    String inputStr = reader.nextLine();

    int[] a = new int [10];
    String[] numb = new String [10];

    int space = inputStr.indexOf (" ");
    int length = inputStr.length(); 

    for (int x = 0; x < numb.length; x++){

        numb [x] = inputStr.substring (0, space); 
        inputStr = inputStr.substring (space+1);

        int num = Integer.parseInt (numb[x]);
        System.out.println (num);
        a[x] = num;
    }
    return a;
}
```

This at the moment get the first number, then shorten the string. How would I go about finding the next number and ending it with out having it going out of bound ? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using string's split method:

```
String[] numbers = numb.split(" ");
int[] a = new int [numbers.length];

for (int x = 0; x < numb.length; x++){
        a[x] = Integer.parseInt (numbers[x]);;
}
```

Comment: Thank so much. It was very helpful and understandable.